# How to build protocol buffer by Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, protocol-buffers, porting

I want to built a native version of Google's protocol buffers library.
How would I do that?

Comment: Just a suggestion. First build it in Java, and then if you need the further optimization move to the NDK. At least in Java you will get the basic protocol down.

Comment: Have you tried simply using the C++ implementation supplied by google?

Comment: Here's my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44773137/529442

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I Use this Android.mk and build SUCCESSFUL

```
    # Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project
    #
    # Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
    # you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
    # You may obtain a copy of the License at
    #
    #      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
    #
    # Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
    # distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
    # WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    # See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
    # limitations under the License.
    #
    #

    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
    CC_LITE_SRC_FILES := \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc                              \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/once.cc                                \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/hash.cc                                \
        src/google/protobuf/extension_set.cc                             \
        src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc                    \
        src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc                              \
        src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc                            \
        src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc                          \
        src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc                           \
        src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc                       \
        src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc


    COMPILER_SRC_FILES :=  \
        src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/extension_set.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/message.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/service.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/code_generator.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/command_line_interface.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/main.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/plugin.pb.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/subprocess.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/zip_writer.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_enum_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_extension.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_file.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_generator.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_helpers.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_message_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_primitive_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_service.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/cpp/cpp_string_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_enum_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_extension.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_file.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_generator.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_helpers.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_message_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_primitive_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/java/java_service.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_enum.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_enum_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_file.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_generator.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_helpers.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_message.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_message_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/javamicro/javamicro_primitive_field.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/python/python_generator.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/io/printer.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/hash.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/once.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc

    # C++ full library
    # =======================================================
    #include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE := libprotobuf
    LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional

    LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cc

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := \
        $(CC_LITE_SRC_FILES)                                             \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc                             \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc                          \
        src/google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc                  \
        src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc                                \
        src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc                             \
        src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc                       \
        src/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc                           \
        src/google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc                       \
        src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc              \
        src/google/protobuf/message.cc                                   \
        src/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc                            \
        src/google/protobuf/service.cc                                   \
        src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc                               \
        src/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc                         \
        src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc                               \
        src/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc                            \
        src/google/protobuf/io/printer.cc                                \
        src/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc                              \
        src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc                  \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc                         \
        src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/src

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/android \
        bionic \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/src \
        $(JNI_H_INCLUDE)

    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := \
        libz libcutils libutils
    LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lz
    # stlport conflicts with the host stl library
    ifneq ($(TARGET_SIMULATOR),true)
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += external/stlport/stlport
    LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES += libstlport
    endif

    # Define the header files to be copied
    #LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS := \
    #    src/google/protobuf/stubs/once.h \
    #    src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.h \
    #    src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.h \
    #    src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.h \
    #    src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.h \
    #    src/google/protobuf/extension_set.h \
    #    src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite_inl.h
    #
    #LOCAL_COPY_HEADERS_TO := $(LOCAL_MODULE)

    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DGOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: This is slightly out of date. For protobuf 2.4.1 hash.cc doesn't exist, so it should be removed. If going up to protobug 2.5.0, same deal plus you need to add src/google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc

Comment: @gkanwar when I make the edits you suggest, the lib compiles but I get this error when I try to call my method that depends on the protobuf libs:
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1306]:    37 cannot locate 'strtof'...

using "nm" I notice the strtof method is listed but has a "U" listed next to it.   Is there a library I'm not including that is required for protobuf to work?

Comment: @MichaelNguyen strtof should live in the stl library. libprotobuf uses stlport; the build file described in the answer links it as a shared library rather than static, so you should be loading libstlport from the Java as well. You can find an example that works in a project I'm working on here: https://github.com/IDKJava/the-elements/blob/master/TheElements-dev/src/com/idkjava/thelements/MainActivity.java#L605

Comment: How did you get this to build? i get a ton of errors. i'm trying off of tag 2.6.1. i get errors like `/src/google/protobuf/stubs/hash.h:172:55: error: expected '{' before '<' token`. why does the regular C++ compile, but for android it doesnt?

Comment: okay, i finally got it to build. use this instead: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/protobuf/  you will have to heavily modify the ANdroid.mk file to get it to work.

Comment: I'm getting  **No rule to make target `jni/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc** while building .mk file. Any suggestion what I'm missing.

Comment: @DavidT. any chance you could put the steps you used in an answer? Not necessarily the mods you made to the `Android.mk` file (though that would be awesome), but at least things like any exports, what you ran, etc.

Comment: somehow i ended up getting it to work. thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Android.mk mentioned above works fine, thanks a lot.

I would like to describe all the steps for building protobuf for android.

- Configure sources for android.
  Use the following script (got it here: http://habrahabr.ru/post/119693/):

  PREBUILT=/Users/user/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3

  PLATFORM=/Users/user/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/

  export CC="/Users/user/android-ndk-r7b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-   4.4.3/prebuilt/darwin-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gcc"

  export CFLAGS="-fPIC -DANDROID -nostdlib"

  export ANDROID_ROOT="/Users/user/android-ndk-r7b"

  export LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/lib/"

  export CPPFLAGS="-I$ANDROID_ROOT/platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include/"

  export LIBS="-lc "

  ./configure --host=arm-eabi
- Delete the following lines from mentioned above Android.mk file:

  ```
  src/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc             \
  src/google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc                          \
  src/google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc                  \
  src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc                                \
  src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc                             \
  src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc                       \
  src/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc                           \
  src/google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc                       \
  src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc              \
  src/google/protobuf/message.cc                                   \
  src/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc                            \
  src/google/protobuf/service.cc                                   \
  src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc                               \
  src/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc                         \
  src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc                               \
  src/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc                            \
  src/google/protobuf/io/printer.cc                                \
  src/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc                              \
  src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc                  \
  src/google/protobuf/compiler/importer.cc                         \
  src/google/protobuf/compiler/parser.cc
  ```

  It is needed for building lite version of library.
  Unfortunately full version of the lib works just from Android 2.3.
  I tested lite version for Android 1.6, 2.1, 2.3.
- build the library using ndk-build.
- for generating c++ files (using protoc compiler) for the lite library it is needed to include: option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME; in .proto file.

Comment: when I remove the mentioned lines  I get a compilation error.  Are you sure that those lines need to be removed?

Comment: You seem to have forgot to set sysroot at CPPFLAGS: 

    `export SYSROOT=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-9/arch-arm`
    `export CPPFLAGS="--sysroot=$SYSROOT"`
    `./configure options`