# NDK. Protobuf library linking

Tags: android, c++, gcc, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

Good day. I compiled protobuf 2.4.1 library with ndk. Script I took from that post:
[How to build protocol buffer by Android NDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144008/how-to-build-protocol-buffer-by-android-ndk)

But when I try to link my library to test cocos2d-x project I gets next errors:

```
SharedLibrary  : libgame.so
./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/protocol.pb.o: In function `promowall::RegistrationRequest const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<promowall::RegistrationRequest const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*)':
/usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:396: undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/protocol.pb.o: In function `promowall::RegistrationResponse const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<promowall::RegistrationResponse const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*)':
/usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:396: undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/protocol.pb.o: In function `promowall::InstallIntentRequest const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<promowall::InstallIntentRequest const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*)':
/usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:396: undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/protocol.pb.o: In function `promowall::ItemRequest const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<promowall::ItemRequest const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*)':
/usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:396: undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/protocol.pb.o: In function `promowall::ItemResponse const* google::protobuf::internal::dynamic_cast_if_available<promowall::ItemResponse const*, google::protobuf::Message const*>(google::protobuf::Message const*)':
/usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:396: undefined reference to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message'
./obj/local/armeabi/objs-debug/game_shared/__/__/Classes/protocol.pb.o:/usr/include/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.h:396: more undefined references to `typeinfo for google::protobuf::Message' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/libgame.so] Error 1
```

As I can see from this log compiler can't find message type. But source file message.cc and message_lite.cc were included in libprotobuf.so library.
Source code of my test application Android.mk listed below

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := protobuf
LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libprotobuf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libprotobuf.so

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := game_shared

LOCAL_MODULE_FILENAME := libgame

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hellocpp/main.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/AppDelegate.cpp \
                   ../../Classes/HelloWorldScene.cpp \
              ../../Classes/protocol.pb.cpp

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Classes

LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := protobuf

LOCAL_WHOLE_STATIC_LIBRARIES := cocos2dx_static cocosdenshion_static cocos_extension_static

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,CocosDenshion/android) \
$(call import-module,cocos2dx) \
$(call import-module,extensions)
```

I will be very grateful for any help :)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307352/g-undefined-reference-to-typeinfo

Comment: Try adding `LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lprotobuf` to the Android.mk and removing it from `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES`

Comment: Btw, may be wrong here but if I remember correctly, `LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES` should contain `libprotobuf`, not `protobuf`.

Comment: I think library links correctly, because if I remove LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES string then compiler throws much more errors

Comment: LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES may be protobuf or libprotobuf: NDK can understand both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log suggests that you didn't turn on RTTI support. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support#rtti for instructions:

> To enable RTTI across your whole application in ndk-build, add the following line to your [Application.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/application_mk.html) file:
>
> ```
> APP_CPPFLAGS := -frtti
> ```
>
> To enable RTTI for a single ndk-build module, add the following line to the given module in its [Android.mk](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/android_mk.html):
>
> ```
> LOCAL_CPP_FEATURES := rtti
> ```
>
> Alternatively, you can use:
>
> ```
> LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -frtti
> ```

Comment: Would you please *accept* the answer so that the question can be closed?

Comment: The link is broken. Please copy the answer.