# How to build lib protobuf along with dynamic library for use in Android application?

Tags: android, c++, dll, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to compile an open source project (let's say `foo`) into a `libfoo.so` native library to use for my android app. However, this project also uses google's protocol buffer library.

So i was able to compile Google's lib protobuf for iOS as follows: https://gist.github.com/BennettSmith/7150245 .

However, this just generates `libprotobuf.a` file. The problem is that I can't seem to figure out a way to include this `libprotobuf.a` file to my `libfoo.so` file for use with my android application. I *THOUGHT* i had referenced it when i did:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := libprotobuf
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ./src/lib/libprotobuf.a
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := ./src/include
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

in my `Android.mk` file. However, it seems that it is definitely not getting linked properly. Whenever i try to `ndk-build` the open source project (which depends on using lib protobuf), i get a bunch of undefined references, like:

```
undefined reference to 'google::protobuf::internal::empty_string_'
```

so then i thought that maybe i'm not supposed to have the symbols defined here? like maybe i'm supposed to first compile the `libfoo.so` file, and then somehow link lib protobuf as `libprotobuf.a` or `libprotobuf.so` ?? so i ended up using `LOCAL_ALLOW_UNDEFINED_SYMBOLS := true` to just get my project to generate the `libfoo.so` file.

but this `libfoo.so` gives me some load error as soon as i try to use it within my android app:

```
dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZN6google8protobuf11MessageLite15ParseFromStringERKSs" referenced by libfoo.so
```

So I'm wondering:

- How do i include this protobuf library in my android app?
- Do i try to include this protobuf library into `libfoo.so` first?
- Would it even work if i tried to ignore linker warnings and then tried to generate `libprotobuf.so` and include that with my application?
- is it even possible to generate `libprotobuf.so`? I can't generate it using the instructions on their github - i get a ton of errors

Note that the only reason i'm even able to get `undefined reference` errors when trying to generate `libfoo.so` is because i manually copied all of the `*.h` in google's lib protobuf.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: The script you link to looks designed for iOS/OSX. I'm not sure it makes sense for Android. The script appears to pass `--disable-shared` to the `configure` script, which disables building of shared libraries, hence you only get a `.a` file and not `.so`. It also does a lot of other weird-looking things that probably don't make sense on Android. I don't have much experience with Android builds so I can't fully answer the question.

Comment: I tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7144008/how-to-build-protocol-buffer-by-android-ndk but it is outdated, or just 2.6.1 doesn't work. any ideas?

Comment: Cross-compiling protobufs should be just like cross-compiling anything else that uses automake/autoconf, except that you have to deal with protoc. (1) compile and install `protoc` on the build machine, (2) `make distclean`, (3) `./configure host=arm-linux-androideabi --with-protoc=protoc`, (4) `make`.

Comment: In my tinkering so far, it seems that `libprotobuf.a` does not like to be part of `libstuff.so` .I'm able to build it, but when running it, I am greeted by the message which goes: `libprotobuf FATAL google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc:87] This program was compiled against version 3.0.0 of ...`.  I have all correct versions so this error message is salty. Moreover, when i link `libprotobuf.a` to `helloworldapp` it works. So the intermediate dynamic library is what protobuf do not like. I'm still on-going...