# Protobuf android NDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build protobuf 2.6.1 NDK using android studio but I don't know how to include protobuf in gradle file also I have tried Android.mk and eclipse non of them working, please help me on this.

```
    LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE    := libprotobuf

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES :=\
    src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/descriptor.pb.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/dynamic_message.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/extension_set_heavy.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/extension_set.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/generated_message_reflection.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/generated_message_util.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/coded_stream.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/gzip_stream.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/printer.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/strtod.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/tokenizer.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl_lite.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream_impl.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/io/zero_copy_stream.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/message_lite.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/message.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/reflection_ops.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/repeated_field.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/stubs/once.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/stubs/stringprintf.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/stubs/structurally_valid.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/stubs/strutil.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/stubs/substitute.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/text_format.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/unknown_field_set.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/wire_format_lite.cc \
    src/google/protobuf/wire_format.cc

    ifeq ($(TARGET_ARCH),x86)
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_SRC_FILES) \
    src/google/protobuf/stubs/atomicops_internals_x86_gcc.cc

    endif

    LOCAL_CFLAGS := -D GOOGLE_PROTOBUF_NO_RTTI=1
    LOCAL_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11
    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES = $(LOCAL_PATH)/src

    LOCAL_EXPORT_LDLIBS := -lz
    LOCAL_EXPORT_CFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CFLAGS)
    LOCAL_EXPORT_CPPFLAGS := $(LOCAL_CPPFLAGS)
    LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_C_INCLUDES)

    include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: _"I have tried Android.mk and eclipse non of them working"_ Then you should include that Android.mk file in your question. It's impossible for anyone else to know what you might have done wrong simply by reading that "you've tried it".

Comment: And what are the errors you're getting when trying to build with this makefile?

Comment: @Michael I followed [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7155854/2624806) to get rid of it. But I'm getting **No rule to make target jni/src/google/protobuf/stubs/common.cc**. Any suggestion what I'm missing there!

Answer (score 0):

I added new module to my project and named it proto. And here is my gradle file for it:

```
apply plugin: 'protobuf'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'ws.antonov.gradle.plugins:gradle-plugin-protobuf:0.9.1'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.6.0'
}

protocPath = 'C:/Users/Paul/proto/protoc'
extractedProtosDir = "${project.buildDir.path}/extracted-protos"
generatedFileDir = "${projectDir}/src/main/java"
//protobufCodeGenPlugins = ['foo:./protoc-gen-foo', 'bar']

dependencies {
    // If you have your protos archived in a tar file, you can specify that as a dependency
    //   ... alternative archive types supported are: jar, tar, tar.gz, tar.bz2, zip
    protobuf files("src/main/protos/dungeon.proto")
    // Different configuration fileSets are supported
    //testProtobuf files("src/main/java")
}
```

Then in my app build.gradle I added `compile project(':proto')`

And finally in my settings.gradle I have `include ':app', ':proto'`

Hope it helps